# Flex skinnableDatacontainer not the owner of the itemrenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

I have a skinnableDataContainer that I extended with some properties that I would like to use in my itemRenderer.

When I try to call (from the itemrenderer)

```
extended_SkinnableDataContainer(owner).myProperty
```

I get an error stating  that **owner is a List and cannot be converted to extended_skinnabledatacontainer**

Is the owner not the hostComponent?

Or is the hostComponent just something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid, the owner IS the hostComponent, I was however still working with a debug version (where I used a list component to test the renderer)